# How to remove only words that end with period with Regex?

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove suffixes from a list of last names using regex:

```
names <- c("John max Jr.", "manuel cortez", "samuel III", "Jameson")
lapply(names, function(x) str_extract(x, ".*[^\\s.*\\.$]"))
```

Output:

```
[1] "John max Jr"

[[2]]
[1] "manuel cortez"

[[3]]
[1] "samuel III"

[[4]]
[1] "Jameson"
```

What I am currently doing, does not work.... I was trying to remove all words that end with a period.
If you could please help me solve this and explain, it would be greatly appreciated. I also need to remove roman numerals but hopefully I can figure that out after learning to remove words ending in period.

Desired Output:

```
John max
manuel cortez
samuel
Jameson
```

Updated to remove Roman Numerals:

```
lapply(names, function(x) str_extract(x, ".*[^(\\s.*\\.$)|(\\sI{2}+)]"))
```

Comment: I am only focusing on trying to remove "Jr." in this question. I do need to remove roman numerals if someone wanted to help out but I am just trying to figure out how to remove words ending with ".". It is only removing the period.

Answer (score 2):

If we just want to `remove` something, maybe `str_remove()`
is better:

```
library(stringr)

lapply(names, function(x) str_remove(x, "\\w+\\.$")) |>
    trimws()

"John max"      "manuel cortez" "samuel III"    "Jameson"
```